# How to receive incoming calls to a Twilio Number from a Web Browser?

Tags: java, twilio

Using Twilio for Java, I want to know the process on how to be able to make our Call Client application receive calls from an Incoming call to a Twilio Number.

[image]

Whereas each "Call Client" is a web browser.

- What are the steps to achieve this?
- What is required in the web browser-based application to be able to receive calls?
- What is the strategy to be able to "map" a *Twilio Worker* into a specific browser?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you want here is a combination of [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter) and [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript).

TaskRouter will take care of queuing calls and routing them to available agents. Twilio Client will let you take calls in the browser.

To understand this better, I recommend you first go through this [TaskRouter tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/quickstart/java), followed by the [Twilio Client JavaScript quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart) and that should give you enough to put the two together and take your TaskRouter routed calls in the browser.

One further thing, if you are looking to build out some sort of contact centre where agents can take calls in the browser and hook into other services, you might want to consider [Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/flex) which can do all of this out of the box for you and then gives you the flexibility to extend the way you want to.

Let me know how you get on.